# Vim keyboard shortcut to replace ^M

Tags: vim

I manually replace `^M` with
`:%s/<ctrl-v><ctrl-m>//g` after I open a log file. I have to do this several times a day so I tried to assign <kbd>F11</kbd> key to perform this action.
I tried the following in *.vimrc* but it did not work.

```
:nnoremap <silent> <F11> :let _s=@/ <Bar> :%s/^M//e <Bar> :let @/=_s <Bar> :nohl <Bar> :unlet _s <CR>
```

***Note:*** I pressed <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd><kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd> to get `^M` in the above statement.

I have a similar assignment for <kbd>F10</kbd> to remove EOL whitespace and that works.

```
:nnoremap <silent> <F10> :let _s=@/ <Bar> :%s/\s\+$//e <Bar> :let @/=_s <Bar> :nohl <Bar> :unlet _s <CR>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that your terminal actually forwards <kbd>F11</kbd> to the commands it’s running instead of listening to the key itself. For instance, the default configuration of Windows Terminal intercepts <kbd>F11</kbd> and does not forward it, so you can’t rebind the key inside Vim.

Furthermore, your command looks quite convoluted; my Vimscript knowledge is limited but if the purpose of your command is to change Windows file endings into UNIX file endings, the following, simpler command works:

```
:nnoremap <silent> <F11> :set fileformat=unix<CR>
```

There’s also a widely installed utility program, [`dos2unix`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dos2unix), that does the same, and which might be even simpler for your use-case.

Comment: dos2unix is not available in the server I'm working on. `:set fileformat=unix<CR>` also did not do anything. But when I changed **F11** to **F12** it worked! I had to change the search pattern to \r instead of ^M. Here is the working shortcut I have in my .vimrc

`:nnoremap <silent> <F12> :let _s=@/ <Bar> :%s/\r//e <Bar> :let @/=_s <Bar> :nohl <Bar> :unlet _s <CR>`